Why is there extra blank space at the bottom when using CoordinatorLayout?
After I used CoordinatorLayout and added a BottomAppBar, there is a blank area between the BottomAppBar and the bottom gesture bar. Is this a bug?
The problem is that I use the CoordinatorLayout layout and add a BottomAppBar to this layout. I set the position of the BottomAppBar at the very bottom. It should be close to the navigation bar. However, there is a blank area between the BottomAppBar and the navigation bar. This is beyond my expectation. I don't understand why such a problem occurs.
This is my xml file：
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_root_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_login_config"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_login_config"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frame_layout_login_config">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_include_login_config_normal"
                layout="@layout/fragment_login_config_normal" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_include_login_config_loading"
                layout="@layout/fragment_login_config_loading"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_include_login_config_success"
                layout="@layout/fragment_login_config_success"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_include_login_config_failure"
                layout="@layout/fragment_login_config_failure"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar$Behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

enter image description here
I don't know why this is the case. After I used the fitSystemWindow attribute for CoordinatorLayout, the blank area became larger.
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

enter image description here
I expect there to be no blank areas when using CoordinatorLayout. At the same time, I want to know the reason for the appearance of blank areas here.

Maybe you can use enableEdgeToEdge() in your activity's onCreate method, before calling setContentView().

try giving android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" to BottomAppBar

android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"  doesnt work T_T
